# Why it compiles whether or not "extern" is used?

Tags: c++, compilation

In a.cpp:

```
int t()
{
  //definition goes here
  ...
}
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
  t();
}
```

finally a.h:

```
extern int t();
//int t();
```

Both forms of a.h works,why?

Comment: This depends on what command-line you are using to compile, IIRC.

Answer (score 9):

Because function are extern by default, so the extern keyword is redundant. Some people like to explicitly add the extern when they want to hint other developers that the *definition* of the function are not to be found in the .cpp file with same name than this .h file, then they add a comment to point where the function is declared. But to the compiler's perspective, it does not affect anything.

Comment: What about variables? I tried `int j;` and `extern int j;` in a.h,still both work...

Comment: Variables work differently, @Wp2. Without `extern`, you'll have a new definition of `j` in every unit that includes *a.h*. In the code you've shown, you only include that file once, in *b.cpp*, but if you include it anywhere else, then you'll have *multiple definitions*, which C++ forbids, although compilers are not required to complain about it.

Comment: @Wp2: That is not portable C. Although C strictly prohibits multiple *definitions* of a function/variable (one-definition-rule), it does not disallow a variable/function to be *declared* multiple times in different files. Some compiler treats `int j;` only as a *declaration*, and infer whether it is also a *definition*, thus implicitly inserting `extern` in all but one of the declarations/definitions. You can force the compiler to treat it as a definition by typing `int j = 0;` which forces the compiler to both *declare* and *define* `j`. This should fail on all compiler.

Comment: So the conclusion is for .h files to be used in multiple .cpp files,declare variables as extern,right?

Comment: @wp2: corret. An alternative way to saying you should never declare/define a variable in headers, only declare functions and classes in headers. But if you really, really, really need to, then you must declare it as extern.